# Why do chaining declarations followed by an instantiation cause a NullPointerException?

Tags: java

I thought I understood `NullPointerException`, but apparently not. This here throws an error:
(`main` is a class)

```
main.topicActionWeight.add(
    Float.parseFloat(this.actionGenreWeightCombo.getSelectedItem().toString()));
```

`TopicActionWeight` is a list. Here is my declaration of the list:

```
public static List<Float> topicActionWeight,
        topicAdventureWeight,
        topicRPGWeight,
        topicStrategyWeight,
        topicSimulationWeight = new ArrayList<>();
```

The lists I declare aren't pointers, are they? They are created..

Yes, I have tried `new ArrayList<Float>();`

Comment: probably `getSelectedItem()` returns null. Or even `actionGenreWeightCombo` (that's one of the reasons I hate chaining function calls, because you never now where such an error occurs)

Comment: First of all, there are no "pointers" in Java language-wise. All objects, however, are typically **implemented using pointers.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By executing the below line you are only declaring all the respective arraylists but not initializing none of them except topicSimulationWeight which is why your topicActionWeight is null and hence the NPE.

```
public static List<Float> topicActionWeight,
        topicAdventureWeight,
        topicRPGWeight,
        topicStrategyWeight,
        topicSimulationWeight = new ArrayList<>();
```

The correct way of initializing is :-

```
public static List<Float> topicActionWeight = new ArrayList<>();
public static List<Float> topicAdventureWeight = new ArrayList<>();
public static List<Float> topicRPGWeight = new ArrayList<>();
public static List<Float> topicStrategyWeight = new ArrayList<>();
public static List<Float> topicSimulationWeight = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you! My 'code buddy' told me that it was much faster and efficient if I did it in one "declaring".

Comment: Take everything your code buddy says with a grain of salt from now on.